# Get pandas groupby().apply() result as a series of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe on which I call `df.groupby('foo').apply(bar)` where `bar` is a function that return a dataframe. I want the result to be a series with index of the different values of `foo` and elements being the different dataframes returned by `bar` (the inuitvie result as this is how `groupby().apply()` behaves with all other return types of `bar`).

However instead I get a multi index dataframe with the first index being the different values of `foo` and the second index being the index of the dataframes that are returned by `bar`. How can I convert it to the desired format?

Comment: Why do you want a series of dfs in the first place? I'm relatively new to Pandas, but I don't see how that could be useful. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832); give the context. Hypothetically, your end goal might actually work fine with a multi-index df (maybe with some minor tweaks), or maybe you'd be better off with a dict of dfs keyed by `foo` value or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to use [`group_keys=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to drop the group key:

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
      Year               Top Seed Record  No. of teams  No. of games
0  2010-11          Chicago Bulls  62–20            30            82
1  2011-12          Chicago Bulls  50–16            30            66
2  2012-13             Miami Heat  66–16            30            82
3  2013-14      San Antonio Spurs  62–20            30            82
4  2014-15  Golden State Warriors  67–15            30            82
5  2015-16  Golden State Warriors   73–9            30            82
6  2016-17  Golden State Warriors  67–15            30            82
7  2017-18        Houston Rockets  65–17            30            82
8  2018-19        Milwaukee Bucks  60–22            30            82
9  2019-20        Milwaukee Bucks  56–17            30            68
```

and the following function:

```
def bar(df):
    return df['No. of games'] / df['No. of teams']
```

If you don't use `group_keys`, the output will be:

```
>>> df.groupby('Top Seed').apply(bar)
Top Seed                
Chicago Bulls          0    2.733333
                       1    2.200000
Golden State Warriors  4    2.733333
                       5    2.733333
                       6    2.733333
Houston Rockets        7    2.733333
Miami Heat             2    2.733333
Milwaukee Bucks        8    2.733333
                       9    2.266667
San Antonio Spurs      3    2.733333
dtype: float64
```

However if you use this parameter:

```
>>> df.groupby('Top Seed', group_keys=False).apply(bar)
0    2.733333
1    2.200000
4    2.733333
5    2.733333
6    2.733333
7    2.733333
2    2.733333
8    2.733333
9    2.266667
3    2.733333
dtype: float64
```

Now you have a `Series` with the original of your dataframe without the `foo` column.